# Pre-selected dropdown components in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have components for showing dropdown in Angular 8.

I need when pass `id` into components, it pre-selected that item in Angular 8.

I try using this code but it not worked:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
<mat-label>{{formTitle| translate}} *</mat-label>
<mat-select [(value)]="ItemId" [compareWith]="compareCategoryObjects" [(value)]="ItemId"  (click)="onChanged()" >
    <div class="col-lg-12 mt-4 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
        <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>{{'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate}} *</mat-label>
            <input (keyup)="getValues($event.target.value)" matInput  [placeholder]="'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="loading" class="mb-2" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
    <mat-option  (click)="emitdata(item.key)" *ngFor="let item of values" [value]="item.key">
        {{item.value}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

worked

in TS:

```
compareCategoryObjects(object1: any, object2: any): boolean {
    return object1 && object2 && object1.id === object2.id;
}
```

**What's the problem? How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: can you create a demo on stackblitz ?

Comment: Could you post more information, the whole .ts file? Are you sure that the variable that holds the selected value is really "ItemId" (with the first letter in upper case). If you follow the normal naming conventions as you seem to do I would expect it to be "itemId" (first letter in lower case).